# TYPO3 formhandler update-table in finisher_db without uid?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.x with fe-login and formhandler. I created a form, where you can register a new fe-user.
I want to have a 'complete user registration' for,m where the user inputs the username the password and a doi-code for verification.
I thought if formhandler has a finisher-db supporting saltedpassword, it has to have a validator (database -> equalsField -> saltedpassword) as well. But I can't find any.

Something like:

```
validators {
  1.class = Validator_Default
  1.config {
    fieldConf {
      password.errorCheck {
        1 = required
        2 = saltedpassword  <-- does not exist
        3 = isInDBTable
        3 {
          table = fe_users
          field = password
          #or maybe: special = password ?
          showHidden = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I need help here, please.

---

*//Update 2015-08-31*

I got rid of the password field in the formhandler to seperate finish-registration and login as *`@Jost`* mentioned.
Now I have a more sincere problem:

I now have a formhandler form where the user is asked to input his email-address and the doi-code. I wanted to use the finisher_db for updating the user in the db. But the update of formhandler-finisher requires the uid of the element to update. Of course I don't have the uid at this state. Is there another way to use the native formhandler finishers?

If not, can someone please give me a heads up of how to write your own finisher for this purpose?

Comment: Can't you just separate user login and entering of the DOI code? So the user logs in using the core `felogin` form, and the form to enter the DOI code is shown on an access restricted page.

It would probably not be so easy to create a password check in formhandler, because you'd need to check agains the complete chain of auth services, and the form in the browser needs some JavaScript to do the RSA encryption, and so on.

Comment: @Jost: You are right. Done that.
Now I have another more sincere problem. I updated my original post...